# Azure DevOps yaml pipeline, downloaded artifact is empty

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Converting a pipeline from classic to YAML (so I know it works).

I build and my publish artifact task looks like this:

```
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyArtifact'
      artifact: MyArtifact
```

The result when build looks like this:

[image]

I then want to deploy this to a webapp
YAML:

```
- stage: Dev
  jobs: 
  - job: DeployApp
    displayName: Deploy Web App
    pool:
      name: myPrivate
      demands: msbuild
    steps:
    - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      inputs:
        artifact: MyArtifact
    - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
      displayName: 'Deploy App'
      inputs:
        WebAppKind: 'Web App On Windows'
        azureSubscription: 'edited out...'
        WebAppName: webAppName
        package: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
        enableXmlTransform: true
```

Which results in this output in Azure DevOps:

[image]

A difference in *chunks* but since size match very exactly I'm happy.

I then get error on the deployment so I started look in Kudo and can see that in SitePackages all my packages are 1 kb (or empty...). I expected 61.2 MB.

[image]

I took my working classic deployment, and there i had this row:

```
packageForLinux:'$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_MyArtifact/MyArtifact/MyApplication.zip'
```

But that path wasn't even found. And packageForLinux felt wrong but doesn't matter as I understand it.

So can someone please me in the right direction how to deploy a web app (on windows) using YAML?

Comment: The folder that's used is `$(Pipeline.Workspace)`, not `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`, the default folder is different for different tasks, so you can't  always trust they extract to the default working directory.

Comment: @jessehouwing thank you very much! That was exactly it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The folder that's used is `$(Pipeline.Workspace)`, not `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`, the default folder is different for each task type, so you can't always trust they extract to the default working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I've wasted a lot of time deciphering these folder paths. I'm adding this info to help anyone else with this issue. Obviously my artifact was empty because my staging folder was empty.

After a few hours of digging I discovered that `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` represents the root of where my dacpac files are built to

In my case I'm using the `CopyFiles` task as it supports wildcards. So whatever dacpac files are generated under the bin subfolder will be picked up and copied to the artifacts staging directory

```
# Build and publish the database solution

trigger:
- master

# this builds on a self hosted pool rather than the MS cloud agent
pool:
 name: MySelfHostedPool
 demands: 
 - MSBuild
 - SqlPackage

steps:
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: Build DB solution
  inputs:
    solution: MemberDB.sln
    logFileVerbosity: diagnostic
# Copy build output to artifact staging directory so they can be published as artifacts in the next step
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: Copy dacpac to artifacts staging
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    flattenFolders: true
    Contents: '**\bin\**\*.dacpac'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: Publish dacpac
  inputs:
    artifactname: 'drop'
    targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```