# FAILED TO INITIALIZE RUN FROM PACKAGE.txt

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

Our pipeline indicates success after deployment.

When looking in "Kudo console" in folder `wwwroot` i observe the following behavior:
[image]

Deploy Task is nothing special:

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy Frontend'
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: # subscription #
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: # appname #
    packageForLinux: # package #
```

The artifact that gets build is approx. 17 MB of size and exists. I downloaded it. It is a ZIP file that can be extracted.
[image]

When looking at `data\sitepackages` i observe the following behaviour:
All deployment runs have a size of **1 KB**.
This explains why the ZIP cannot be extracted.
But WHY is it 1 KB?
[image]

**UPDATE (1):**

When we use the feature "Zip Push Deploy" from "Kudo Console" we can drag&drop the ZIP file that we have downloaded from our artefacts before.
**The zip gets extracted and the app is working!**
This means the ZIP in the artefacts is not corrupt.

[image]

**UPDATE (2):**

The complete run indicates success and produces a artefact with 17 MB. After Deployment the size of the ZIP file is 1 KB. There has to be an issue with the deploy task?

[image]

**UPDATE (3):**

Screenhot from Deploy Step that also shows success:

[image]

**UPDATE (4):**

MSFT support suggested to use V3 of the deploy Job: `AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3`.

Different output:
[image]

Same result.

**UPDATE (5):**

i have recreated the app service in the meanwhile (deleted and created).

Same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am almost certain that the package path is not correct in your yaml step. Should be something like below. Unfortunately, the misleading part is pipeline shows succeeded with the wrong path.

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy Frontend'
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: # subscription #
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: # appname #
    packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/*.zip'
```

There is also a [similar past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56805440/azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-downloaded-artifact-is-empty).

Comment: thanks for the hint. i am going to verify that. interestingly i never found the mentioned 'similar past question'. i keep you updated.

Comment: You solved it by saying: ´the misleading part is pipeline shows succeeded with the wrong path.´ we found we had a variable pointing to the wrong ZIP file.
The Task: `AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4` should simply throw an error when it is not finding the ZIP!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The same error can happen when you're deploying to a new app service and directly to an app service slot that is configured incorrectly.

If you add a DevOps task `Deploy Azure App Service` and you deploy to the production slot rather than the swap slot, and then later add a task `Azure App Service manage` to swap it with the swap slot. You will have an empty website with no zip package but the pipeline will still have completed successfully.